# HTML is changed before the copying of the image is completed leading the image to not being displayed in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my Electron program I copy a file to an other directory and then change the `src` of the `<img>` tag in the HTML to the new path (the file that was created by copying the other file).
The problem is that, apparently, the copying is not finished when the `src` is changed which leads the window to displaying only this [image: broken-image-placeholder-image].
I have solved this by adding a timeout before the `src` is changed which is, indeed, a really bad solution.

Is there a way to call the `update_GUI()` function (changes the `src`) not before the copying is completed?

Here is the code:

```
//new_sprite_path is the path from which the image is loaded from,
//sprite_path is the path of the image when it is in the programs' file system

function load_sprite(){
  let new_sprite_path = `` + dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile'], title: "Load sprite", filters: [
    {name: "Images", extensions: ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "jpe", "jif", "jfif", "jfi", "gif", "png", "svg", "bmp", "dib", "ico"]},
    {name: "All Files", extensions: ["*"]}
  ]});
  //copy image
  if(new_sprite_path === undefined) return;
  sprite_path = `${__dirname}/../../project_files/sprites/` + path.basename(new_sprite_path);
  fs.createReadStream(new_sprite_path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(sprite_path));

  if(sprite_path != "undefined" && sprite_path != undefined) update_GUI();
}

function update_GUI(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("sprite_thumbnail").src = sprite_path;
  }, 2000);
  document.getElementById('name').value = path.basename(sprite_path);
  document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = path.basename(sprite_path);
}
```

Comment: You should use event handlers. I believe you need to use something of the likes: `fs.on("end",function(){update_GUI()});` source: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

Comment: Thank you very much! It was `readable.on("end",function(){update_GUI()});`

Comment: No problem! Side note, you should be able to simplify it to `readable.on("end",update_GUI);` - just depends on your preference